# Small x axis range in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I try to plot data in pgfplots. My data file has 1001 points in a range (x axis) from 2499999500 to 2500000500, so I have steps of 1. I get the message “Package pgfplots Warning: Axis range for axis x is approximately empty; enlarging it (it is [2499999500.0000000:2500000500.0000000]) ...” in the log file and a straight line is drawn, the axis limits range from 2e9 to 3e9, overriding them with `xmin = ...` etc. does not help. Any idea what can be done?

File test.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        xmin=2499999500,
        xmax=2500000500,
      ]
      \addplot+ table [x index=0, y index=1] {testdata.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

File testdata.dat:

```
2499999500 0
2500000000 1
2500000500 0
```

Comment: This requires at least 9 digits of precision for the x-values. I think this is beyond the precision of the underlying math code. As your x-axis labels would be quite long anyway I would suggest subtracting a constant. I can plot the data easily with something like `table[x expr=\thisrow{x}-2500000000]` and add a note in the x axis label or something similar.

Comment: @Alexander oh I just spent some time figuring that out then I noticed you'd put the answer here. I won't post my answer in that case, I suggest you post this as an answer since I can confirm independently that it works:-)

Comment: Hm, that works for the little example above, but if I insert real data (1001 points, too big to post here) I get another rounding issue: several steps. You could test it by generating a test file with a spreadsheet program, the numbers from 2499999500 to 2500000500 in the first column and a ramp (1, 2, 3, ...) in the second.

Answer (score 4):

Not quite an answer but a workaround is using an expression such as:

```
\addplot+ table [x expr=\thisrow{x}-2500000000] {\mytable};
```

to subtract a large common number from the dataset. This still uses the math engine of pgf and works for your small test case.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
2499999500 0
2500000000 1
2500000500 0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xtick=data, xticklabels from table={testdata.dat}{[index]0}]
  \addplot+ table [x expr=\thisrowno{0}-2500000000] {testdata.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For closely spaced data this still breaks down. The precision of the FPU engine can be shown with

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
\pgfmathparse{2500000400 - 2500000500}
\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
```

Which prints zero as the change occurs at the 8th digit. So I would recommend using either gnuplot as suggested in the pgfmanual or preprocessing the dataset externally.

Alternatively the `fp` package is more suited to the problem as it operates with fixed point. I do not know how to integrate it with pgfplots.

---

**Update:**

Whereas with LaTeX the precision is limited it is not a problem to use LuaTeX for the calculation here and the results are quite nice. If run with LuaTeX the following example produces the correct output:

```
\documentclass[tikz,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8} 

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread
{
x y 
2499999500  1
2499999501  2
2499999502  3
2499999503  4
2499999504  5
2499999505  6
2499999506  7
2499999507  8
2499999508  9
2499999509  10
}\mytable;

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot+ table [x expr=\directlua{tex.print(\thisrow{x}-2499999500)},y=y] {\mytable}; 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: New example with lua]

Comment: I added a MWE and a picture to your answer. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Luigi: Thank you for the MWE. I guess the real answer would involve using a math engine with more precision. Maybe pgf can use lua for that in the future.

Comment: You can use `x expr=\directlua{tex.print(\thisrowno{0}-2500000000)}` in order to evaluate your expression using `lualatex`. It has higher precision.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: Thank you for the hint, I feared that it would be tricky but this is works nicely and without large modifications.